# The method 'getInstance' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAppCheck'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-app-check

I am trying to use firebase new feature which is App check. I am following the instructions from their documentation [app check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android-debug-provider).

For this line

```
FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance();
```

The method `getInstance` isn't defined for the type `FirebaseAppCheck`.

Does anyone know what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
FirebaseAppCheck firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.instance;
```

Comment: this works. but i have another problem which is "The method 'installAppCheckProviderFactory' isn't defined for the type 'FirebaseAppCheck'.". do you know hov to solve this?